# Sbt assembly for multiple targets

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to create fat jars for multiple version of scala using sbt assembly.

When I target a single version, I write in `simple.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

And the fat jar is output to `target/scala-2.11/Kernalytics-assembly-1.0.jar`. Now I would like to also target Scala 2.12. I could edit the sbt file to change scalaVersion, but I would like the assembly process to be automated over a range of versions of Scala when I call `sbt assembly`.

If I use `crossScalaVersions`:

```
name := "Kernalytics"

version := "1.0"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.12", "2.12.4")

libraryDependencies  ++= Seq(
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.13.2",
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-natives" % "0.13.2",
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-viz" % "0.13.2"
)

libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.6"

resolvers += "Sonatype Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % "test"
```

The only output is `target/scala-2.12/Kernalytics-assembly-1.0.jar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `crossScalaVersions` I think you need to prefix the command with a '+' if you want to build for all versions.

From [Cross-Building a Project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Cross-Build.html#Cross-Building+a+Project):

> To build against all versions listed in crossScalaVersions, prefix the action to run with +

Comment: As a note, in the command line the + must be joined with assembly, as in `sbt +assembly`